# QPixmapCache in PyQt6

Tags: python, user-interface, qpixmap, pyqt6

Hello I am trying to create a PyQt6 widget that animates over a set of images, but at a precise frame rate that varies as a function of realtime parameters. I insert `QPixmap`s into the cache within a for loop, and am able to find the `QPixmap` objects through `QPixmap.find()` within the same for loop, but outside the loop `.find()` returns `None`.

Below is the script. I can include the image series if needed. Appreciate any help.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QLabel
)
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPixmapCache
from pathlib import Path

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.animating_label = QLabel('animation here')
        self.animating_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)
        self.animating_label.pixmap().size().setWidth(200)
        self.animating_label.pixmap().size().setHeight(200)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.animating_label)

        parent_path = Path(__file__).parent
        self.images_path = parent_path / 'images/animation_set/'
        self.animating_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.images_path.__str__() + "/clock01.png"))

        self.pixmapcache_keys: [str] = []

        self.load_images()
        test = QPixmapCache.find("clock02")
        try:
            self.animating_label.setPixmap(test)
        except:
            if test == None:
                print("Failure: QPixMapCache.find() returned", test)

    def load_images(self):
        image_suffixes = ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp']
        imgs_found_count = 0
        for filepath in self.images_path.iterdir():
            if filepath.suffix in image_suffixes:
                imgs_found_count += 1
                cache_key = filepath.stem
                self.pixmapcache_keys.append(cache_key)

                if not QPixmapCache.find(cache_key):
                    pixmap = QPixmap(filepath.__str__())
                    QPixmapCache.insert(cache_key, pixmap)

                print("pixmap %s" % cache_key, QPixmapCache.find(cache_key))


        print(imgs_found_count, "image(s) found in animation_set directory.", len(self.pixmapcache_keys),
              "keys loaded into QPixmapCache")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

# start Qt event loop
app.exec()

print("Script complete.")
sys.exit(1)
```

Here is the output:

```
pixmap clock04 <PyQt6.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x101c84b30>
pixmap clock10 <PyQt6.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x101c84970>
pixmap clock11 <PyQt6.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x101c84b30>
pixmap clock05 <PyQt6.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x101c84970>
...

24 image(s) found in animation_set directory. 24 keys loaded into QPixmapCache
Failure: QPixMapCache.find() returned None
Script complete.
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not surpassing the [`cacheLimit`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmapcache.html#cacheLimit)? Besides, if it's only for internal usage in a single widget, can't you just store the images (not the pixmaps) in memory?

Comment: @musicamante I should have mentioned the total size of the image set is 314KB, so definitely below the default limit. I haven't found a way to set an image to fill a QLabel in the documentation. I was able to get the animation working by instatiating a list of QPixmaps and iterating through them using `Qlabel.setPixmap(pixmap)`. But is that the optimal and most efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the animation working using a list of QPixmaps instead of QPixmapCache, but I am not sure if this is the optimal approach.

Generating Qpixmap list from files:

```py
        for filepath in sorted(self.images_path.iterdir()):
            if filepath.suffix in image_suffixes:
                qpixmap = QPixmap(filepath.__str__())
                self.pixmaps.append(qpixmap)
```

called elsewhere on a timer

```py
    def advance(self):
        if self.pixmap_current_index >= len(self.pixmaps) - 1:
            self.pixmap_current_index = 0
        else:
            self.pixmap_current_index += 1
        self.animating_label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[self.pixmap_current_index])
        self.timer.start(self.refresh_interval)
```